# Регулярное выражение preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

У меня на сайте в новостях есть такие данные. Название разное, а смысл тот же. Сейчас переношу все отдельно по полям в базу данных и не могу никак выловить текст (вот такое) регулярным выражением:

```
Год: 2014<br />
год: 2014<br />
год выхода: 2013-2014<br />
Год выхода: 2013-2014<br />
```

Пытаюсь вот так:

```
'year' => '#(Год\|год).*?:(.+?)<br />#si',
```

Ничего не получается. Как все-таки правильно выловить значение после `:`?

Comment: @czart2014, вы бы объяснили, что на выходе должно быть по каждой позиции.

Необходимо ли выбирать записи, указанные в диапазоне `Год выхода: 2013-2014`. Если да, то по какой границе считать или необходимо выбирать всю строку `2013-2014`? Есть ли вёрстка вокруг вашего блока, который Вы представили в примере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = 
"Год: 2014<br />
год: 2015<br />
год выхода: 2013-2014<br />
Год выхода: 2013-2014<br />";

if (preg_match_all('/год:\s*(?P<year>\d{4})/iu', $content, $matches)) {
  var_dump($matches["year"]);
}
```

[**Смотрите результат**](http://ideone.com/uS9SFe)

#### Обновление

Вариант с диапазоном

```
$content =
    "Год: 2014<br />
год: 2015<br />
рейтинг: 9999<br />
год выхода: 2013-2014<br />
качество: хорошо<br />
Год выхода: 2014-2015<br />";

if (preg_match_all('/год[^:]*?:\s*(?P<year>\d{4}(?:\-\d{4})?)/iu', $content, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches['year']);
}
```

[**Смотрите результат**](http://ideone.com/UUo0Ui)

Comment: Тоже не верно. Вы обратите внимание, что ищет, только где маленькая буква г!

Comment: @czart2014  И что? Флаг `i` означает, что все вхождения нерегистрозависимые. Вы смотрели пример? Все 4-ре значение выводятся.

Comment: Второй вариант получился удачный. Только в текст может быть еще у меня Качество: ... и куча других вариантов. А мне нужно только выдернуть только год.

Comment: @czart2014

> Тоже не верно

Прежде подобное писать, Вы посмотрите на представленные результаты. Если Вас что-то не устраивает, то сформулируйте задачу точнее. Возможно, представленные Вами входные данные не точны. Здесь телепатов нет.

Comment: Ну посмотрите, что у меня в тексте есть такие данные - я привел пример какие. Тут и телепатом не нужно быть что не только данные могут быть после : за год

Comment: @czart2014 Исправил ответ и пример. Добавил качество.

Comment: @czart2014 А если кто-то вместо слова `год` вбил `гад`. Или вообще, не `год`, а `период`. Для написания регулярного выражения необходимо знать все нюансы.

Answer (score 1):

`\|` - так вы заэкранировали спецсимвол.
Вместо `Год` или `год` у вас ищется прямым текстом `Год\|год`.
Конечно же, совпадений нет.

Вот вам улучшенное регулярное выражение:

```
#год[^:]*?:\s*(\d{4}(?:\-\d{4})?)<br \/>#siu
```

`iu` - благодаря этим флагам у вас регистронезависимая регулярка
`год[^:]*?:` - `год` в любом регистре, затем максимально короткая последовательность любых символов, кроме двоеточия, потом двоеточие
`\s*` - произвольная по длине последовательность пробельных символов
`(\d{4}(?:\-\d{4})?)` - либо 4-х значное число, либо 4-х значное число, дефис и еще одно 4-х значное число. `?:` указывает на то, что группу в скобках не нужно запоминать.

**[Посмотреть пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/dS2bP9/1)**

Comment: Странно очень. Делаю вот так в php:

    $re = "/год[^:]*?:\\s*(\\d{4}(?:\\-\\d{4})?)<br \\/>/siu"; 
    $str = "Год: 2014<br />\nгод: 2014<br />\nгод выхода: 2013-2014<br />\nГод выхода: 2013-2014<br />"; 
 
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

    echo $matches[1];

На экране пусто. Что не так?

Comment: @czart2014, с помощью `echo` нельзя распечатать массив, а у вас именно массив значений в результате. Используйте `print_r()`